# JavaScript stuck on accessing style element from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a program to change the x value of a SVG element on load (ultimately intended to be part of a mapping program). My code is getting stuck on trying to access specific values of each element, and I'm not sure why.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <svg width="12cm" height="12cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="a" x="40" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="b" x="100" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="c" x="160" y="180" width="30" height="30"
  fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="d" x="220" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var array1 = [a, b, c, d];

    array1.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);
      var xValue = document.getElementById(element).style.x;
      xValue = xValue * 2;
      document.getElementById(element).style.x = xValue;
      console.log("done");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can tell that the JavaScript is accessing the information inside the SVG, because the console logs the entire element with the ID from the array. However, I can also tell that the JavaScript is getting stuck on trying to access a specific attribute of the element, because the console only logs the first line of the code, and only for the first element in the array.

Ultimately, what should be happening is that the JavaScript gets an ID from the array, accesses that element, accesses some attribute of that element (in this case, the x value), performs a transformation on that attribute, and changes it (so, if this were working, the x location of each SVG element would shift by a factor of 2).

I'm sure the issue here is my syntax but I can't quite figure out why. I tried using `.innerHTML` and it didn't help.  Here's a CodePen to see it in action. If you open the console you can see the first line log: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBqNrK?editors=1111

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If `element` really is the SVG node, you don't need to call `getElementById()`. You already *have* the element, so you don't have to "get" it.

Comment: That said, those `<rect>` elements won't have a "style" property with an "x" sub-property; you probably need `.getAttribute("x")` to get that value.

Comment: Can you check the whole html and ensure that there is no other element with name "a,b,c,d" ?

Comment: Ohhhh. Pointy- That makes a ton of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a hint from Pointy and some quick debugging I've figured this out!

Here is the solution: First, there was no reason to be using `.getElementById()`, as I'd already accessed the element. I also had to use `.getAttribute()` instead of `.style.x`, change the `*` to `=*`, and use `.setAttribute("x", xValue)` to change the value.

Here is the final, functional code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <svg width="12cm" height="12cm" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="a" x="40" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="b" x="100" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="c" x="160" y="180" width="30" height="30"
fill="#000"/>
    <rect id="d" x="220" y="180" width="30" height="30" fill="#000"/>
  </svg>
  <script>
    var array1 = [a, b, c, d];

    array1.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element);

      var xValue = element.getAttribute("x");
      console.log(xValue);

      xValue *= 2;
      console.log(xValue);

      element.setAttribute("x", xValue);
      console.log(xValue);

      console.log("done");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With a lot of `console.log()`s for debugging, where the code was stopping and how values are changing.

Here's a codepen that shows the program working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GBqNrK?editors=1111

Hopefully this'll be helpful to someone eventually!